# Using Jekyll how to convert each element of a list in index.md to a custom <div> tag in the generated html file?

Tags: html, jekyll, static-site

I am creating a very simple single page Jekyll site. All it does is render the list in the `index.md` file - which one can keep adding to or deleting elements from - as pre-defined `<div>` tags in the html file that is eventually generated.

I am very new to using Jekyll and am not able to figure out, any google search leads me to *collections* and *for* loops which haven't necessarily helped so far.

An example `index.md` content would be -

```
## TITLE

- Element A
  * Subelement A
- Element B
  * Subelement B
- Element C
- Element D
  * Subelement D1
  * Subelement D2
```

All I have in `default.html` is -

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
        {{ content }}
    </body>
</html>
```

But let's say the idea is to render the elements in the list as something like [this](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/books/notable-books.html) (to keep it simple let's assume that we had only a single column instead of 3).

Not necessarily looking a baked answer but any hint and (or) resource on this would greatly help.

**EDIT 1:**
My folder structure is as follows which i'd like to preserve -

```
# Directory structure
.
|__ _layouts
|   |__ default.html
|__ assets
|__ _config.yml
|__ index.md
```

My `config.yml` is empty.

The only thing that I will edit would be the `index.md` file where I will add more list elements. That just needs to be rendered in its own `<div>` tag in the `index.html` file.

**EDIT 2:**
Turns out what I want is the Jekyll equivalent of Hugo's `shortcodes`
A preliminary research tell me that I should look into Jekyll `includes` and `tags`.
I think I can perhaps simplify my question in this way -
How to convert each element of a markdown list to a custom `<div>` tag using Jekyll ?

**EDIT 3:**
When given the following Markdown contents, I expect to get the following HTML contents -

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
        <div class="column-card">
            <div class="list-element">
                <p>Element Content</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="subelement-content">
                <p>Sub-element content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        .....this repeats for more list elements.....
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the sections are Markdown content converted into HTML, use collections and iterate.
For example, I'll use a collection named `tutorials`:

```
# _config.yml

collections:
  tutorials:
    output: true
```

with the following directory structure:

```
# Directory structure
.
|__ _layouts
|   |__ default.html
|__ _tutorials
|   |__ Example A
|   |__ Example B
|__ _config.yml
|__ about.md
|__ index.md
```

Then in the `default` layout:

```
<section>
  {% for doc in site.tutorials %}
    <article>
      <div class="article-title>
        {{ doc.title | default: Sample Article }}
      </div>
      <div class="artcle-summary">
        {{ doc.excerpt }}
      </div>
      <a href="{{ doc.url }}" title="Read More..">Read More</a>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

---

The above is for creating sections of content. If you just need to render simple strings of text, use data files. For example, when I have the following in a data file at path
`./_data/navigation.yml`:

```
- label: Home
  url: "/"
- label: About Site
  url: "about.html"
- label: Contact Us
  url: "contact.html"
```

Then my layout content would be:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {% for item in site.data.navigation %}
      <li>
        <a
          href="{{ item.url | relative_url }}"
          title="{{ item.label }}"
        >{{ item.label }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Documentation: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/

Comment: I need to just render simple strings of text - list elements in the index.md markdown file to be precise. I thought that in jekyll there would be a way to iterate over the list and generate <div> tags in the index.html in _site folder. However it looks like I haven't understood jekyll or how it works properly. My setup is quite simple. There will ONLY be a single markdown file - index.md - whose contents i'd keep on changing and I just want jekyll to render that in a defined way in a single html page like the example New York Times url.

Comment: I found some relevant information and updated the question. Please have a look, I think its more to the point now.

Comment: Jekyll is not a super-smart program that calculates what you intend to get and deliver that. Instead it is a simple program that converts Markdown into HTML and places that HTML content into a given HTML layout. Coming back to your question, Jekyll may not be what you're looking for. However, you may help others in answering if you edit your question to include the resulting HTML as well. i.e., *When given the following Markdown contents, I expect to get the following HTML contents..*

Comment: If you know someone who can write a Ruby plugin for Jekyll to alter its current behavior, you might be able to achieve this. The only possible way to achieve this with Jekyll out-of-the-box is with data files and loops in the layout.